# Search a sheet then copy column to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am trying to search a sheet in my workbook, look for specific timestamps and then copy the corresponding row to a separate sheet. I used the macro recorder to get an idea of where to start, which helped in building the array. But the specific data i need wont always be held in the cells "C4" for example.

I'm a bit unsure how to search the whole file for this array and then copy the column to the sheet named Database

Thanks!

```
Sub CopyData()

    Sheets("temp7").Range("$A$1:$J$141091").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "02/22/2018 00:00:00", "02/22/2018 01:00:00", "02/22/2018 02:00:00", _
        "02/22/2018 03:00:00", "02/22/2018 04:00:00", "02/22/2018 05:00:00", _
        "02/22/2018 06:00:00", "02/22/2018 07:00:00", "02/22/2018 08:00:00", _
        "02/22/2018 09:00:00", "02/22/2018 10:00:00", "02/22/2018 11:00:00", _
        "02/22/2018 12:00:00", "02/22/2018 13:00:00", "02/22/2018 14:00:00", _
        "02/22/2018 15:00:00", "02/22/2018 16:00:00", "02/22/2018 17:00:00", _
        "02/22/2018 18:00:00", "02/22/2018 19:00:00", "02/22/2018 20:00:00", _
        "02/22/2018 21:00:00", "02/22/2018 22:00:00", "02/22/2018 22:00:00"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    Range("A27").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "02/22/2018 00:00:00"
    Sheets("Database").Select
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "02/22/2018"
    Range("C4").Select
    Sheets("temp7").Select
    Range("F27:F577").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Database").Select
    Range("B2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A28").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: So you're filtering, putting some values in some cells and then copying a range from one sheet to another. What exactly do you need help with?

Comment: It looks like you are looking for all times in the day, except maybe one? Possible filter for the one that does not equal that time. Or filter for a specific day, and then filter for between two time periods.

Comment: I will have a file with a number of dates and associated data in this format. I really want to search for say 1/5/18 at 23:00 to the 2/5/18 at 23:00 and copy the data in the next cell across to a new sheet. Then do this for the next date until no data is found